# Generate random numbers in advance in another thread in c++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, random, c++11

For some numerical simulations in c++ I need to generate many random number with exponential distribution (all with the same predetermined distribution). Currently, my program works well, but more than 50% of the CPU time is spent generating these random numbers.

What I would like to do is generate these random numbers in a way that does not block the main loop of the simulation. More precisely, I would like to have a thread whose job is to always keep a random number "ready in advance", and immediately generate a new one when somebody reads this random number.

Does anybody know of a nice way of doing this?

Currently, my sequential code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

// exponential random variable with parameter lambda
class EXPGenerator{
    exponential_distribution<> expo;
    mt19937 engine; //mersene twister
public:
    EXPGenerator(double lambda){
        expo = exponential_distribution<>(lambda);
        engine = mt19937(time(NULL));
    }

    double step(){  
        return expo(engine);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    EXPGenerator expgen(2.0);
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
        double randv(expgen.step());
        std::cout << randv << endl;
        // do something complicated
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it using `clang++ -O2 --std=c++11 --stdlib=libc++ test.cpp -o test`

[EDIT: added -O2 above]

Comment: Why are you basing decisions on the performance of an *unoptimized* build? Before you go for any complex and hard-to-maintain solutions test whether you actually have a real problem *at all*. The code might be fast enough once you enable optimizations.

Comment: The program above is just an example to actually base my question on something. I have already optimized the real program as much as I could, and it still takes a few hours to run... We are talking about simulating stochastic diffusion processes, which require thousands of time steps and thousands of simulations for good statistics...

Comment: *You are compiling without optimizations enabled*

Comment: Indeed, so says the command line above. But the real program (much too long to be shown here) is compiled with -O2. I should have put the -O2 in my original question, sorry.

Comment: Fair enough. :) And yeah, showing that in the original question would have avoided some confusion But as long as you base your measurements on an optimized build, that's the main thing ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a bounded queue and have one thread pushing random numbers into this queue and let that thread block on the queue, when the queue is full. To get a random number, pull a number out of this queue and let the consumer thread block on the queue, when the queue is empty.

This simple design will let the producer produce random numbers, when there is room in the queue and cpu time available.

Optimization: Use a queue with lists of random numbers. In this case, the producer will produce a complete list with random numbers. The consumer will keep a cache (probably inside of EXPGenerator) with a list out of the queue. Once the cache is empty, the cache will be filled with a new list from the queue. This will reduce the context switch overhead and should (of cause) only applied, when measuring shows, that this makes sense.

The queue should basically be some std::deque with T being a random number, or std::vector (a list of random numbers). Use a mutex to synchronize the access to that std:queue and use two condition variables. One, to signal that there is room to insert more random numbers again. And one to signal, that there is already at least one element in the queue. Let the consumer wait for the second condition, when the queue is empty and let the producer wait for the first condition, when the queue is full.

Answer (score 6):

The first thing you should try is to enable optimizations. Try adding a -O2 option to the clang command line.

Comment: Yes, I have tried -O2, and even tough it does reduce the execution time by some factor, the actual simulation still takes a few hours, which could probably be cut by half by generating the random numbers in another thread.

Comment: I should have put it in the question, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

When you work with optimizations (as others suggest) you can create a bunch of random numbers in an other thread store them in a vector and use a message queue to transport it to your main thread. There you can wrap it into your `EXPGenerator`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like to do. And unfortunately, I don't know how to implement it. I'll have a look at how message queues work.

Comment: @Nown The queue should basically be some std::deque<T> with T being a random number, or std::vector<double> (a list of random numbers). Use a mutex to synchronize the access to that std:queue and use a two condition variables. One, to signal that there is room to insert more random numbers again. And one to signal, that there is already at least one element in the queue. Let the consumer wait for the second condition, when the queue is empty and let the producer wait for the first condition, when the queue is full.

Answer (score 2):

There's an optimization possible here that I don't think anyone has mentioned yet.

I don't see any reason that a consumer thread waiting for random numbers should ever block waiting on the producer thread.  That is, if the cache of random numbers runs dry, rather than blocking, just produce one or more random numbers on the consumer thread itself before checking the cache again.

Not needing blocking communication also makes it much easier to use lightweight, lock-free data structures for the inter-thread communication.  Good candidates include:

- libcds: http://libcds.sourceforge.net/
- intel TBB: https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/

In fact, if you only have a single "helper thread", the special case of communicating between exactly one producer and one consumer can be done with a circular buffer without any atomic memory operations at all.

Answer (score 1):

OK, first create your random-generating thread.  Since thread sync is relatively expensive compared with generating one random, loading up a vector, (say with capacity 10k), with randoms, (as suggested by Jan), is a good idea.  Thread creation, termination and destruction is also a PITA, so loop the 'random' thread round a wait on a 'go' AutoResetEvent, (see MSDN), initialized to true- the thread will then generate a vector of randoms on startup and then whenever 'go' is signaled.

You need a mechanism to wiat until the vector is completely assembled before taking ownership of it.  You could post it on a producer-consumer queue, a Windows message queue maybe, as suggested by Jan, hovever it may be easier, ( in this case), to just take the vector from the thread when it's done. You could use another 'complete' AutoResetEvent, initialized to false and wait on it, the random thread signaling it when it's done.

A soon as you take a vector, signal the 'go' event to start the random thread generating another vector so that it will probably be already complete when you need it later.

You need a vector instance where ownership can be easily transferred. I would probably just use a pointer, creating one with new in the random thread, generating the randoms, copying the pointer value in the main thread and delete'ing it when done.  The random thread would just new another vector whenever it passes 'go', so reseating its own pointer.  If you have a suitable smart_ptr class available, you could use that, probably unique_ptr since it can be moved.

Comment: There are mutex and condition variable available in C++11, so there is no need to use windows constructs. And why would you use a pointer over std::vector? You can transfer between two threads easily be swapping them.

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki - yeah, OK, whatever:). Anything to avoid copy ctor.  Also, I misread the tags as I had just been looking at a winapi question :(